# Proving that $(0,1)^3$ not homeomorphic to $[0,3)^3$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

What are some of the various ways of proving that $(0,1)^3$ is not homeomorphic to $[0,3)^3$ using the fundamental group and homology groups? I feel like I have various ways of understanding why this is true in terms of point-set topology but I would like some help with developing an algebraic approach.

Both spaces are contractible, so the fundamental group won't be able to tell them apart. Maybe if i remove a certain point from both of them it will? For that matter, is it wrong for me to think of $[0,1)^3$ as a closed octant of $\mathbb{R}^3$? That's what it looks like to me, as I believe $[0,1) \cong [0, \infty)$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest an indirect proof.  Assume they are homeomorphic with a homeomorphism from $[0, 3)^3$ to $(0, 1)^3$.  Now look at the image of a neighborhood of (0, 0, 0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $[0,3)^3 \setminus \{ (0,0,0) \}$ is contractible, but $(0,1)^3 \setminus \{ x_0 \}$ is not contractible for any $x_0 \in (0,1)^3$.

Comment: What is an easy way to understand why the first one is contractible but the second one isn't?

Comment: the fact that the first one has a closed endpoint?

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom: You can deformation-retract $X = [0,3)^3 \setminus \{ (0,0,0) \}$ onto any point in $X$ by linear homotopy. For example define $H : X \times I \to X$ by $H(x,t) = (1-t)x + t(1,1,1)$.

Comment: Ah, so you can remove that point and the set is still convex. Is that the only point that that is possible for?

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom: No, in fact you can remove any of the points on $[0,3)^3 \cap \partial([0,3)^3)$ (i.e. on one of the three faces that is included in the cube), and obtain a contractible space. If you remove any point other than $(0,0,0)$ then it won't be convex, but it will still deformation-retract via linear homotopy onto any point in the interior, which is $(0,3)^3$. (I chose $(1,1,1)$ because it looks nice.)

Comment: is $(0,1)^3 - \{p\} \cong \mathbb{R}^3- \{p\}$? If so, then we have $\mathbb{R}^3- \{p\} \cong S^2 - \{p\}$ which is contractible, is it not?

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom: Why do you think that $(0,1)^3 - \{ \text{pt} \} \cong \mathbb{R}^3 - \{ \text{pt} \}$ implies $\mathbb{R}^3 - \{ \text{pt} \} \cong S^2 - \{ \text{pt} \}$? The former is true, but the latter is false (and remains false with $\cong$ replaced by $\simeq$). In fact, $(0,1)^3 - \{ \text{pt} \} \simeq S^2$, not $S^2 - \{ \text{pt} \}$.

Comment: Riiight of course my bad sorry

Answer (score 0):

$(0,1)^3$ is homogeneous and $[0,1)^3$ is not, as a point on the "boundary" (like $(0,0,0)$) cannot be mapped by a homeomorphism to a point of the interior, or vice versa. It probably can be reduced to an argument involving Brouwer's fixed point theorem e.g.